# Aggregating bag of words vectors by word for many files

Tags: r, data-cleaning

I currently have a list of vectors where each number in the list represents the count of a different word in the file.

I would like to change this list to be a dataframe where the rownames are the filenames, and columns are the words (sorted alphabetically with only one column per word), and each observation the count of a certain word, where all words used in any file is included (i.e. if file a includes a word that file b does not include, then the count of the word in file b is 0).

So essentially the current code right now looks like:

```r
file1 <- c(1,5,7,2)
names(file1) <- c("a", "by", "her", "the")

file2 <- c(10,5,2)
names(file2) <- c("a", "and", "to")

list(file1, file2)
```

What I would like is:

```r
df <- data.frame(matrix(nrow=2, ncol=6, byrow=T, data=c(1, 0, 5, 7, 2, 0,
                                                        10, 5, 0,0,0,2)))
colnames(df) <- c("a", "and", "by", "her", "the", "to")
rownames(df) <- c("file1", "file2")
df
```

Thanks.

Comment: I should also mention that this will be done for like 100 files, so huge amounts of repetition would be difficult. Also, it's not absolutely necessary to have them alphabetized, but it would be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `fill` argument of `rbindlist` function from `data.table` package can come in handy here.

```
library(data.table)

nm = c("file1", "file2")
d = rbindlist(lapply(mget(nm), function(x) data.frame(t(x))), fill = TRUE)
d = as.data.frame(d)
row.names(d) = nm
d
#       a by her the and to
#file1  1  5   7   2  NA NA
#file2 10 NA  NA  NA   5  2
```

To reorder `d` and replace `NA` with `0`, further steps are necessary

```
d = d[,order(colnames(d))]
d = replace(d, is.na(d), 0)
```